# Drupal database size

Tags: database, drupal-6

I have a site in drupal, at times its really slow have to reboot the server.

I see mysql is consuming too much resources.

I have a core table for drupal devel_times: it contains over 846,000,000 rows and the table itself is about 30 Gb, is that not causing the problem, because I see each time it logs entries, can I empty that table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if [this issue](http://drupal.org/node/141457) is related to drupal 5, I think it's still valid. So I would definitely say yes, you can delete those records :)

Comment: Hey thanks for your help will see to it :) . I think there is some way to turn that off in devel settings in drupal also.
Thanks,
Veer :)